# Javascript Object/Array population question

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Is there a difference between:

```
 var samples = {
        "TB10152254-001": {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "001",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"
        },
        "TB10152254-002": {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "002",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"
        },

        "TB10152254-003": {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "003",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"
        }
    };
```

AND

```
 var samples = new Array();
samples["TB10152254-001"]  = {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "001",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"};

samples["TB10152254-002"] = {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "002",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"
        };

samples["TB10152254-003"] =  {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "003",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"
        };
```

EDIT:

I will re-phrase the question: 
How do I populate the hash dynamically? 
I can't do something like samples.TB10152254-003 because i TB10152254-003 is dynamic...so, is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will work because an Array is a type of object. But there isn't any advantage to using an Array this way, and can easily give trouble when you iterate over the properties using a `for/in`.

The Object would be the proper type to use for named properties. Reserve your use of Array for index properties only.

---

With regard to your edit, you can dynamically populate the Object the same way as the Array, using square bracket notation.

```
   // Create a new empty object. You an use "new Object()" if you wish
var samples = {};

  // Populate the "samples" object in the same way you would an Array.
samples["TB10152254-001"]  = {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "001",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"};

samples["TB10152254-002"] = {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "002",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"
        };

samples["TB10152254-003"] =  {
            folderno: "TB10152254",
            ordno: "003",
            startfootage: "",
            endfootage: "",
            tagout: "Y"
        };
```

Comment: actually they don't both work. I pass this to the ajax function (Jquery ajax) and it only likes the first one. I was under the impression they are equivalent....(and yes I jasonify it before passing it on).

Comment: @gnomixa: I mean they both work in terms of successfully storing the values against the named properties. There can and likely will be side effects, which is why I said to use the Object (first one).

Comment: ok, so how do I dynamically populate the hash? no one seems to answer this. I mean, it's not always possible to define it statically....I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the second example example, you are "abusing" the fact that an `Array` as also an `Object`. Don't do this.

Use `Array`s for numerical indexed values only and plain `Objects` for kinda hash tables.

I suggest to read more about [`Array`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) and [`Object`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects).

In JavaScript, basically everything is an object. Also arrays. But the `Array` object provides additional methods for dealing with numerical indexed data.

You can probably see the difference the best when you do `samples.length` in the second example. A plain object has no property `length`, an array does. For an array, it tells you the number of elements stored in the array. Now when you call `samples.length` in the second example, you will get `0` because the array actually holds no element.

What might lead to more confusing is the fact, that you have two possibilities to access object properties: The "dot notation", `object.property` and the "array notation", `object['property']`. But this is a functionality of objects not of arrays.

The array notation comes in handy, when you generate the keys or have the property name stored in a variable.

**Update:**

As written, you can make use of the array notation to create properties dynamically, e.g.:

```
var samples = {};

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    samples["TB10152254-" + i] = {
        folderno: "TB10152254",
        ordno: i,
        startfootage: "",
        endfootage: "",
        tagout: "Y"
    }
}
```

If you want to access the properties, you have to use the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate over the keys:

```
for(var key in samples) {
    var value = samples[key];
}
```

But note: Never ever use `for...in` to loop over an array. On the page I linked to is also written why.